# Ionic example for adding authentication to Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

This tutorial:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users/

walks through how to add third-party authentication to your Cordova app. Unfortunately, it doesn't apply to Ionic apps - the index.html file in an Ionic app doesn't come with a Content-Security-Policy tag, for example, and there's no index.js file at all.

Does anyone know how to accomplish in Ionic what this tutorial describes?

Answer (score 2):

The index.js file is just a JavaScript container for the code - you should be able to translate to an Ionic app pretty easily.  Similarly, just add the Content-Security-Policy to the index.html file - it's fairly standard.

That being said, Ionic is basically Angular under the covers.  There is an [Angular sample](https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ContosoMoments/tree/master/src/Cloud/ContosoMoments.API/app) contained within our [ContosoMoments sample](https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ContosoMoments) - look at the js/controllers/authController.js file for an example on how to login with an Angular controller.